# how to merge like&match sql query in mysql format?

Tags: mysql, sql

how to merge these 2 sql query in mysql format?

```
SELECT id, category, location
FROM table
WHERE
(
    category LIKE '%keyword%'
    OR location LIKE '%keyword%'
)
```

and:

```
SELECT id, description
FROM table
WHERE MATCH (description) AGAINST('keyword1 keyword2')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `UNION`, but you will need to have the same amount of columns in each query.

```
SELECT id, category, location
FROM table
WHERE
(
    category LIKE '%keyword%'
    OR location LIKE '%keyword%'
)

UNION

SELECT 
id, 
NULL as category,
description
FROM table
WHERE MATCH (description) AGAINST('keyword1 keyword2')
```

If you want rows that are duplicated between queries (i.e., a row that is returned by both queries separately) to appear more than once, then change `UNION` to `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 0):

How about using `and`?

```
SELECT id, description, category, location
FROM table
WHERE (category LIKE '%keyword%' OR location LIKE '%keyword%') AND
      MATCH (description) AGAINST('keyword1 keyword2');
```